# Add New Dummy Row at the Top with Data Binding Telerik Grid

Tags: c#, telerik

i want to add row at top of the Telerik Grid. i bound Data  in that grid. i want dummy row with DB Binding value. it tried the following but it doesn't work

```
 radGridView1.Rows.AddNew();
 radGridView1.Rows.Add("***********************","******");       
 this.purchase_DetailsTableAdapter.Fill(dt);  //data binding
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this Telerik documentation link: [Adding and Inserting Rows in RadGridView control](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-rows-adding-and-inserting-rows.html). After adding new row to the RadGridView, you may try to rebind the RadGridView. See this link: [RadGridView data rebind](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/rebinding-the-radgridview-on-a-button-s-click-event.aspx).